# PHP: Delete unique values from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to delete all unique values from an array.

So lets say I have `$array = (1,2,3,5,4,3,4,5,234)`

the function should delete all unique values and output:

```
$newarray = (3,5,4,3,4,5)
```

I just thought of a solution with `array_count_values` but I do not know how I could iterate it. Furthermore I am sure there is a more elegant and efficient way to do this. Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of solutions:

```
$array = [1,2,3,5,4,3,4,5,234];
$freq = array_count_values($array);
print_r(array_filter(
    $array,
    function ($v) use ($freq) { return 1 < $freq[$v]; }
));
```

Comment: a very elegent version! thank you very much! What should I do if my array has the format like: Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 4 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 3 [5] => 4 [6] => 3 [7] => 4 [8] => 41 [9] => 42 [10] => 43 [11] => 44 [12] => 45 [13] => 46 [14] => 47 [15] => 48 [16] => 49 [17] => 50 ). It seems like not to work for this array version

Comment: Not to work __how__? Please provide expected result and what you got.

Comment: I get: Array ( ) and expected the new array with removed values.

Comment: its working now thank you! with your function you can even filter all that only appear twice etc. by changing the number 1 to 2 right? I would like to make that number dynamic $maxfreq but that seems to not working correctly if I change  return $maxfreq < $freq[$v]; . What do I need to change in that case`?

Comment: `use ($freq, $maxfreq)` as anonymous function does not have access to `$maxfreq` unless you mention this variable in `use ()`

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = (1,2,3,5,4,3,4,5,234);
$freq = array_count_values($array);

$output = array();
foreach($array as $val){
   if($freq[$val] >1){
      $output[] = $val;
   }
}

print_r($output);
```

May be not the most efficient way.